# Code executing inline but not when it is defined in a function and called by main function in python

Tags: python-3.x, image, function, python-imaging-library

I have a set of code

```
photo = PhotoImage(file = "computer.png")
label = Label(root, image = photo)
label.pack()
```

When it is defined in the main program, it executes. When it is defined in a function as

```
def callback():
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "computer.png")
    label = Label(root, image = photo)
    label.pack()
    print ("click!")
```

then only click! was printed on python shell and nothing else.
This code is to display an image on windows form developed using Tkinter

Call to the function was earlier made with menu command but there was no output than through a button with same result

This is inline code

```
root = Tk()
root.title('View')
root.geometry('600x400')
photo = PhotoImage(file = "computer.png")
label = Label(root, image = photo)
label.pack()
```

This is the function

```
def callback():
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "computer.png")
    label = Label(root, image = photo)
    label.pack()
    print ("click!")
```

call through menu command

```
viewmenu.add_command(label="1:1 Zoom", command=About)
```

call through button click

```
b = Button(root, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()
```

The expected result is to display the image on Tkinter winform and the actual result is nothing just printing click! on python shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, in the inline code, photo object persist in the memory. But when you call the function, since `photo` is a variable defined in the function scope, it's destroyed when function job finishes (its shown and destroyed so fast that you do not notice it). In the code below, when `photo` is defined as a global variable, you get the desired result:

```
from tkinter import *

def callback():
    global photo
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "computer.png")
    label = Label(root, image = photo)
    label.pack()
    print ("click!")

root = Tk()
b = Button(root, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also you can define the `photo` as an attribute of the `root` object:

```
def callback():
    root.photo = PhotoImage(file = "2.png")
    label = Label(root, image = root.photo)
    label.pack()
    print ("click!")
```

Following an object oriented paradigm make organization of the code easier. Please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/11542188) for more information.